# Why is my variable changing when its getter is called?

Tags: java, spring-boot

My project involves SpringBoot. So in a `Service` I've created a method to retrieve the default indices available to all users :

```
@Service
public class UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private IndexRepository indexRepository;



/**
 * Read from application.properties
 *
 * We only store the index ids in the application.properties
 */
@Value("${default.allowed.ids}")
private String defaultAllowedIds;

// I've also tried and removed the static with the same behaviour
private static HashSet<Index> listOfDefaultAllowedIndex = null;

public User findByUsername(String username) {
    return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
}

public User findByResetToken(String resetToken) {
    return userRepository.findByResetToken(resetToken);
}

/**
 * Saves the user in the database and encrypts the password with bcrypt.
 *
 * @param user
 */
public void save(User user) {

    // Code to save a new user

}

public void update(User user) {

    // COde to update the user
}

/**
 * List the default index allowed by default to all users
 *
 * @return the listOfDefaultAllowedIndex
 */
private HashSet<IndexSetup> getListOfDefaultAllowedIndex() {
    
    System.err.println("TEST : DEFAULT LIST CONTAINS " + (listOfDefaultAllowedIndex != null ? 
            listOfDefaultAllowedIndex.size() + " index" : "NULL"));
            // This is null at the beginning then it grows
    
    System.err.println("TEST : THE DEFAULT STRING IS " + defaultAllowedIndexIds); 
    // This is always an empty string

    if (listOfDefaultAllowedIndex == null) {


        // 1) Gets the ids from the property
        HashSet<String> defaultIds = new HashSet(Stream.of(
                defaultAllowedIndexIds.split(
                        SEMI_COLON_SEPARATOR)).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        
        System.err.println("TEST : DEFAULT IDS : " + defaultIds); // THis is empty
                    

        // 2) Converts them into list of Index object
        listOfDefaultAllowedIndex = new HashSet(StreamSupport
                .stream(indexRepository.findAll().spliterator(),
                        false)
                .filter(idx -> defaultIds.contains(Integer.toString(
                idx.getId())))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        
        System.err.println("TEST : CONVERTED INDEX : ");
        listOfDefaultAllowedIndex.stream().forEach(
                    idx -> System.err.println(idx.getName() + " (" + idx.getId() + ")")); // THis is empty

    }
    
     System.err.println("TEST : READING FROM CACHE (FROM THREAD " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ") FOR THE DEFAULT IDS : ");
        listOfDefaultAllowedIndex.stream().forEach(
                    idx -> System.err.println(idx.getName() + " (" + idx.getId() + ")"));
                    // THis should be empty but is growing

    return listOfDefaultAllowedIndex;
}
```

So everytime `getListOfDefaultAllowedIndex` is called the listOfDefaultAllowedIndex grows (actually it would grow if it was a List but it is a Set) although the property in application.properties does not change and `listOfDefaultAllowedIndex`is only changed in that method (when it is null so when the server is reset). I've searched with `Find Usage` or `Find in project` functions from the IDE and could not find any results except in that method.

I noticed that the thread name was different but I can't figure out how a race condition would change the value to something different than empty.

PLease note : I've noticed that if I remove the class variable `listOfDefaultAllowedIndex` as well as the `if listOfDefaultAllowedIndex == null` condition, and declare `listOfDefaultAllowedIndex` in the method, then it works as expected, the `listOfDefaultAllowedIndex` remains empty (in that case where the property is empty), but I can't explain why.

Consequently what could make the variable change ?

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @RalfKleberhoff I was indeed leaking the original `HashSet` by doing this in another method :

```
HashSet<Index> allowedIndexes = this.getListOfDefaultAllowedIndex();
//...
allowedIndexes.addAll(...);
```

This [other old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927810/does-modifying-the-result-of-a-getter-affect-the-object-itself) actually answers mine.

And to combat this I must return an immutable version of the `Set` by wrapping the `Set` into `Collections.unmodifiableSet(listOfDefaultAllowedIndex)` as proposed in the answer below. Wow I completely forgot that!

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probable reason:

You're leaking your internal `HashSet` to callers of your getter.

So, if a caller modifies the `HashSet` it got as return value from your getter, this change will get reflected in your internal field value, as it's the very same `HashSet` object.

To check: return a `Collections.unmodifiableSet(listOfDefaultAllowedIndex)` from your getter (and adjust the return type to be a `Set` instead of `HashSet`). Then any caller trying to change the `Set` will get an exception instead of modifying anything. Then you can decide how to go on: e.g. have this caller make a copy, always return a copy of the field's HashSet

Comment: Thanks @ralf-kleberhoff you nailed it! I forgot only a reference to the object was returned not a copy!