# Returning Unmodifiable List When Using Getters

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class with private fields and I'm using getters to access those private fields:

```
List<Event> get events {
    return _events;
  }
```

The issue is when I get events and change its value, the original value (_events) will change too.

```
userProfile.events.removeWhere((event)=> event.id == "1"); //this modifies _events as well
```

How can I change this behavior so that I only change `events` without affecting the original `_events` value?

I can do it like this:

```
List<Event> get events {
    return [..._events];
  }
```

which is basically a copy of `_events` but is there a way to return it as unmodifiable collection like we do in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16928255/12828249)?

Thanks

Comment: check all `List` [constructors](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html#constructors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `List.unmodifiable()` constructor.

```
List<String> get name => List.unmodifiable(_name);
```

Checkout [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.unmodifiable.html).